# Installing httpd-2.4.3 in RHEL 5.3

Tags: apache, redhat

I have installed `httpd-2.4.3` on `RHEL 5.3`. I followed the basic installation which later then it runs on

```
/usr/local/bin/apachectl restart -f /usr/local/conf/httpd.conf
```

I can access locally (`just use telnet localhost 80`) , but i cannot access from remote using my browser or telnet port 80 from other server.

- adding port 80 to `IPtables`, - done
- `httpd` services is running - checked

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/selinux/config is enable or not.